# Python: Assigning "through" an iterator

Tags: python, reference, iterator, variable-assignment

I have an iterator over a mutable sequence, e.g.

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for bar in foo:
```

Is there a way to write to the elements in foo by using the reference which is contained in the iterator? The naive assignment:

```
   bar = 42
```

does not work of course. Is it possible to use the "behind the curtain" reference to the sequence element which is in the iterator ?

PS: The simple solution with using an index

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   a[i] = 42
```

will not work for my case, as I can't expose the container name.

Comment: You can't expose the container name? Your `for` loop requires a reference, so to get back to the original container all you need is that *same reference*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Imagine that this is an iterator coming out of a class where the true container resides. The iterator will not let me subscript itself.

Comment: In that case you cannot alter the container *anyway*. Python objects can be referenced from many different locations; `bar` is one such reference, the list referenced by `foo` is another. Which one is the 'true' reference you wanted to rebind here? What if I copied the `foo` list into another, should references to `42` be rebound in that list too?

Comment: The class is holding a name which references the list. This list is what I want to modify. I want to do myobject.foo[i]=42 but through the iterator which is just running over myobject.foo[]. It seems impossible to revector a list element (which is a pointer technically) explicitly by only having at hand a "pointer to" the element itself. You seem to need the reference to the start of the list always in Python, correct?

Comment: You do; because the values in the list are immutable, you need to rebind the indices in the list to point to *new* objects. A python list is just a sequence of references, just as variable names are, albeit accessed by index, not by name.

Comment: And I dreamt of a way to modify one of these references by knowing nothing but the reference *to this reference*, but as I understand now, such a beast only exists temporarily as an expression (e.g. foo[1]), but never as an object which could be passed around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my understanding, your use case is something like this:

```
class Z:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = 1, 2, 3

    def it(self):
        for x in self.a, self.b, self.c:
            yield x

z = Z()
for x in z.it():
    if x == 1:
       x = 42 # z.a should be 42? - doesn't work!
```

This isn't possible in python - there's no "pointer" or "reference" data type. You can work around this by yielding a setter function instead of (or along with) the value:

```
class Z:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = 1,2,3

    def it(self):
        for x in 'abc':
            yield getattr(self, x), lambda y: setattr(self, x, y)

z = Z()
for x, setter in z.it():
    if x == 1:
       setter(42) # works!
```

Comment: The use case that I try to solve is "read element and modify(overwrite) it if it meets a criteria", so I would need an iterator which yields me a read and a write function. This could work... thanks, nice one! :)

Answer (score 24):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate indices for you in the loop:

```
for i, bar in enumerate(foo):
    foo[i] = bar + 42
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
foo[:] = [expression for bar in foo]
```

or, if the assignment is too complicated for an expression, you could use a function, `func`:

```
foo[:] = [func(bar) for bar in foo]
```

---

If you only have an iterator, then there is no way to reassign values to the underlying container for there is no guarantee that there even is an underlying container:

```
def generator():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

for bar in generator():
    # Nothing you put here can change what's going on in generator
```