# Zip inside zip does not track changes

Tags: python, list, for-loop, zip, shuffle

I am trying to perform some operations at the same time for two lists. Basically, I have train/test sets together with their labels. If I do something like:

```
x_train=[1,2,3,4]
x_test=[1,4,3,2]
y_train=[4,3,2,2]
y_test=[1,2,4,4]

for x,y in zip([x_train,x_test],[y_train,y_test]):
     x.append(2)
     y.append(3)
```

I will update each list and get
`x_train=[1,2,3,4,2], y_train=[4,3,2,2,2]...`

and so on. However, if after that I try to shuffle them

```
for x,y in zip([x_train,x_test],[y_train,y_test]):
   x.append(2)
   y.append(3)
   c=list(zip(x,y))
   shuffle(c)
   x,y=zip(*c)
```

This still returns `x_train=[1,2,3,4,2],y_train=[4,3,2,2,2] ...`

I can of course shuffle outside the for loop for each set, but in my real case I zip more lists, so this option doesn't look nice.

Comment: Please specify the programming language you're using in the tags section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reassigning a value to an iterator - `x`, `y` in the above example - will not affect the iterated collection in any way, hence the collection - `x_train`, `y_train`, etc. in the above example - is left unchanged.
Example:

```py
items = list(range(5))
for i in items:
     i = i * 2
print(items)  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

See added comments for the original example below:

```py
for x,y in zip([x_train,x_test],[y_train,y_test]):
   x.append(2)
   y.append(3)
   c=list(zip(x,y))
   shuffle(c)
   x,y=zip(*c)  # This has no effect on x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562356/python-assigning-through-an-iterator

Comment: I see, so I will have to do it somewhere else in my code. Thanks!